# Gridview Background color based on gridview datakeyname

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to color my gridview backgroud rowcolor based on the datakey. What I want is for each grouping of datakey names to be colored in grey, and then the next color white, and then the next color grey etc. So alternating based on different datakey names. Here is the code I have below. Can someone help me?

```
protected void grdContents_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //Default values
    string strPreviousDataKeyValue = "";
    Color RowColor = Color.grey;
    foreach (GridViewRow row in grdContents.Rows)
    {
        if (!strPreviousDataKeyValue.Equals(grdContents.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString()))
        {
            row.BackColor = RowColor;
            strPreviousDataKeyValue = grdContents.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So there is your code, did it work? If not, can you specify the problem?

Comment: Why don't you use `<RowStyle BackColor="Gray" /> <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />` in your gridview?

Comment: I am trying to change the color on grouped datakey names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RowDataBound` is executed for every row in the `GridView`. So your `foreach` loop there is pretty redundant. You also have to check for the correct `RowType = DataRow`.

This should work:

```
protected void grdContents_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowIndex == 0)
            e.Row.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        else
        {
            var thisKey = grdContents.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value;
            var prevKey = grdContents.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex - 1].Value;
            var prevRow = grdContents.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex - 1];
            if (thisKey.Equals(prevKey))
                e.Row.BackColor = prevRow.BackColor;
            else
                e.Row.BackColor = prevRow.BackColor == Color.Gray ? Color.White : Color.Gray;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am going for. The code only changed the first two rows grey, though.

Comment: @user1049984: i'm glad to hear that you got it to work, but what was wrong?